# Fulltext Search Not Working With Some Tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so, I have 4 tables in a database (articles). There are, ID (Auto Increment), title, description and content.

Here is the SQL query I used to execute PDO Fulltext Search:

```
$sql = $database->prepare("SELECT *,
MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('*$query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('*$query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC");
$sql->execute();
```

Everything works when I echo it.

However, when I include 'description' into it, it does not work.

```
$sql = $database->prepare("SELECT *,
MATCH(title, content, description) AGAINST('*$query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title, content, description) AGAINST('*$query*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC");
$sql->execute();
```

It did not give me any error message. However, the is no result when I echo it.

I'm using WAMP Server.

Comment: You have to [check for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php#refsect1-pdo.errorinfo-examples).

Comment: How to check for error?

Comment: Are you serious? Open the link. Read.

Comment: I did, but.. there's not error.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible when you created the table the description field wasn't in there and then wasn't in the FULLTEXT key in MYSQL. You can take a look here [Show a tables FULLTEXT indexed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107599/show-a-tables-fulltext-indexed-columns) to see if it is missing the description column.

If it is you need to drop/remove the FULLTEXT search column and add a new one

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(title, content, description)
```